# Prevent QListView flickering on internal move drag and drop

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListView connected to a QStandardItemModel.
When I internally move an item via drag and drop, for a split-second the view shows an additional item, e.g. when moving item 1 in-between item 2 and 3:

```
before:   during:   after:

item 1    item 1    item 2
item 2    item 2    item 1
item 3    item 1    item 3
          item 3
```

In my list setup, this causes a noticeable flickering. Note that it occurs more regularly with more items in a list.

**Question:** Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I have tried messing with `QStandardItemModel::insertRows()`, `QListView::viewport()->setUpdatesEnabled()`, `QListView::blockSignals()`, and more, but to no avail.

Can I prevent the QListView from updating while the item is still being moved around? Can the model be modified to not send update-causing signals? Any other ideas?

Here is a minimum working example demonstrating the problem:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(QString("item %0").arg(i));
        item->setDropEnabled(false);
        model.appendRow(item);
    }

    QListView list;
    list.setModel(&model);
    list.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
    list.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to you question but it works perfectly for me. My conclusion: you are coding the thing correctly and the issue either comes from your computer or from your Qt version. Mine is `Qt 6.5`; what is yours?

Comment: Reproducible (with increased window size) using Qt versions below 6.5.0, I tested with 6.4.3, 6.3.2, 6.2.4. OS: KDE Neon 5.27.

Comment: I‘m encountering this with Qt version 6.5.2 and on macOS, in case this is platform-specific.

Comment: Mine is WIndows and be it on small or maximized window, at the start, middle or end of the list (with 10x more items than your code creates), I can see no flicker... I wonder if it could be caused by a very high screen refresh rate. Would it be possible my screen simply skips a frame and I cannot see it?